# Vuejs2- Get dynamic values from "v-model" , calculate all and display it in the computed property

Tags: vuejs2

My form consists of dynamic table, can add & remove any number of rows. I want to calculate **grand total** whenever user enters values inside the charges field [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4i788.png). At inital stage, "grand total" value will be 0 because I have initialized "enteredValue" value as 0 and return the same. But whenever there is change in the **"row[].charges"** v-model(charges column), "enteredValue" value should update same. Kindly help me to solve this issue.

Here is my code:

```
<template>
<div>
    <b-card>
        <div class="panel-body" id="app">
            <table class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="width: 20px;">No.</th>
                        <th style="width: 330px;">Description</th>
                        <th style="width: 130px;" class="text-right">Charges</th>
                        <th style="width: 130px;"></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr v-for="(row, index) in rows" :key="row.qty">
                        <td>
                            {{ index +1 }}
                        </td>
                        <td>

                        <select class="form-control" v-model="row.billChgDesc" v-validate="'required'" :name="'billChgDesc' + index" data-vv-as="Description">
                            <option v-for="option in billChgDescOpt" v-bind:value="option.value" 
                                :key="option.value"> {{ option.text }} 
                            </option>
                        </select>
                        <span v-show=" errors.has('billChgDesc' + index)" class="is-danger">{{  errors.first('billChgDesc' + index) }}</span>
                        </td>

                                <td> 
                                  <input class="form-control text-right" type="text" v-model="row.charges"  data-type="currency" v-validate="'required'" :name="'charges' + index" data-vv-as="Charges" >
                                     <span v-show=" errors.has('charges' + index)" class="is-danger">{{  errors.first('charges' + index) }}</span>

                                <td>
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" @click="addRow(index)"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
                                    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" @click="removeRow(index)"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                     <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" class="text-right"><strong>GRANDTOTAL</strong></td>
                        <td colspan="1" class="text-right"><strong>{{ grandtotal }}</strong></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>

        </div>
    </b-card>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from 'vue'
import accounting from 'accounting'
import VeeValidate from 'vee-validate'

export default {

filters:{
moneyFormat: function (val){
     if (val > 0) {
            return accounting.formatMoney(val, " ₹ ", 2, ",", ".");
        }
}
}
   data: function () {
    return {
        billChgDescOpt: [
            { value: '', text: 'Select' },
            { value: 'M', text: 'Maintenance Fee'},
            { value: 'W', text: 'Water Charges'},
            { value: 'P', text: 'Penalty Fee'},
            ],
        rows: [
            {qty: 5, billChgDesc: '', charges: 55.20, tax: 10},
            {qty: 19, billChgDesc: '', charges: 1255.20, tax: 20},
        ],
        enteredValue:0
    }

  },
    computed: {
        row.charges:{
           get: function () {
              return this.enteredValue
          }
          set: function (newValue) {
             this.enteredValue = 0;
             let inputValue = parseInt(newValue);
             this.enteredValue = enteredValue+inputValue
             this.enteredValue = inputValue
          }
      },
       grandtotal(){
            return this.enteredValue;
         }
    },
    methods: {
        addRow: function (index) {
            try {
                this.rows.splice(index + 1, 0, {});
            } catch(e)
            {
                console.log(e);
            }
        },
        removeRow: function (index) {
            this.rows.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }
}
</script>
<style lang="scss" scoped>
.is-danger{
  color:  RED;
}
</style>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not quite sure what you are trying to do with the `row.charges` computed property - it should return a function but you are returning an object instead? Does that even compile?

I would suggest you change your computed properties like this:

```
computed: {

   grandtotal() {
        let tmp = 0;
        this.rows.forEach((row) => {
            tmp += row.charges;
        });

        // if you want enteredValue to always be the total charges, uncomment the following
        // this.enteredValue = tmp;
        return tmp;
     }
},
```

Also, I think you have a problem with your `addRow` method. If you add an empty object, your `v-model`s will likely fail since e.g. `charges` is not defined. You could instead try something like this:

```
addRow: function (index) {
        try {
            this.rows.splice(index + 1, 0, {qty: 0, billChgDesc: '', charges: 0, tax: 0});
        } catch(e)
        {
            console.log(e);
        }
    },
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Error in this line " **this.rows.forEach(row) {}** ". This line throws an error such as "';' expected."

Comment: Would you mark my answer as the correct answer then :)? Just click the "check" icon next to the answer.